# How to skip an error in cucumber?

Tags: google-chrome, testing, cucumber, watir-webdriver

How can cucumber skip (ignore) an error without stopping the test? I mean - if an error appears -> the test must be continued.

Answer (score 2):

If an error occurs during scenario, the scenario is failed. I know that sometimes, you've got complex scenario, with a lots of steps to prepare the real test, and it is frustrating that the real test is not executed at all.

The only case where I think it can be good, is when your scenario made a change and should cancel the changes after. But I prefer to deal with that on the steps to initialize the next scenario.

(As you d'ont really know the order of the tests, it can be a little more complicated sometimes)

Answer (score 0):

What about catching the exception in your step definition or underlying code?

Comment: But i don't kwon, where will be an error.
Or tell me please, how can i write an exception?

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to ignore *any* errors occurring *anywhere*?

Comment: yes. I want to see, how many errors I have. And then they all to correct.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? When an error is encountered, Cucumber will stop the current scenario and move on to the next one. At the end of the run, all errors (i.e. up to one error per scenario) are reported. Isn't that enough?

Comment: no. Cucumber stopt, if it found an error... But I want, that this scenario going on.